# Updated to Visual Studio 2022 and not able to update 2017 project to target framework to 5.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I upgraded my Visual Studio to 2022. In the installation I checked off both .NET Framework 5.0 and 6.0 along with other framework versions.

I had a project that I did in 2017 that I wanted to move to target .NET 5.0 since one of my references used 5.0. When I opened the project in Visual Studio 2022, the target framework dropdown only goes up to .NET Framework v4.8 and there is no 5.0 or 6.0 included in the list.

I have tried to do a few things which none worked

1. I tried to manually updating and unloading the project and changing the target frame work to 5.0 but its still asking me to download it even though I've both checked it in the 2022 installation and downloaded and installed it from the website.
2. I've added a global json file with the the

   {
   "sdk": {
   "version": "5.1.0"
   "version": "6.0.0"
   }
   }
3. I've tried changing the toolset on the unloaded project file to 17.0
4. I don't know what else to do to change my project target to 5.0
   5   I've also did a devenv reset to reset my environment.

I have not created a workspace yet for 2022 and I have also deleted the 2017 version thinking that might conflict with it but nothing worked.

Don't know if there is something else I'm missing or not doing.  Thanks

Comment: .NET 5.0 and .NET 6.0 are the next version of **.NET Core** after the v3.1. The "legacy/full" and Windows-only **.NET Framework** goes up to 4.8.1 and no further. If you want to use .NET 5 or 6, you need to switch to the **.NET Core** world and create a **.NET Core** project in Visual Studio.

Comment: What framework was the project in before you started? What results do you get if you run this command line: `dotnet --list-sdks`? What error are you seeing with your project right now?

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant

Comment: @DavidG when i run that comman i get this
1.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.515 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Comment: @marc_s am I able to change my project to the .net core project . There is only one reference that uses .net 5.0 or is there a way for me to satisfy that one reference and keep everything else the same?

Comment: I would (and have) create a new project/solution in .Net 6, then copy over the files from the other project solution and build in a piecemeal fashion until you get it working. The style of the solutions and project files changed considerably in the last 5 years and depending on the project the process can get confused when just updating to the latest.

Comment: Please post your before (and if you have them 'after') csproj files.

Comment: @HansPassant I used the upgrade assistant i tried updating it using the 
upgrade-assistant upgrade --target-tfm-support 5 <Path to csproj>
but it upgraded it with .Net standard 2.0 instead of .net5.0 I tried using the command
upgrade-assistant upgrade --target-tfm-support net5.0 <Path to csproj> but it did'nt
like that nor upgrade-assistant upgrade --target-tfm-support .net5.0 <Path to csproj> but it did'nt what is the proper command to target .NET 5 target framework.